# Method is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have troubles with my unity code when trying to enter playmode
it says

```
Assets/game/Scripts/Effects/Gradient.cs(14,26): error CS0115: `Gradient.ModifyVertices(System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.UIVertex>)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
```

and Gradient.cs looks like this

```css
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[AddComponentMenu( "UI/Effects/Gradient" )]
public class Gradient : BaseMeshEffect
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Color32 topColor = Color.white;
    [SerializeField]
    private Color32 bottomColor = Color.black;

    public override void ModifyVertices( List<UIVertex> vertexList )
    {
        if( !IsActive() )
        {
            return;
        }

        int count = vertexList.Count;
        float bottomY = vertexList[0].position.y;
        float topY = vertexList[0].position.y;

        for( int i = 1; i < count; i++ )
        {
            float y = vertexList[i].position.y;
            if( y > topY )
            {
                topY = y;
            }
            else if( y < bottomY )
            {
                bottomY = y;
            }
        }

        float uiElementHeight = topY - bottomY;

        for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
        {
            UIVertex uiVertex = vertexList[i];
            uiVertex.color = Color32.Lerp( bottomColor, topColor, ( uiVertex.position.y - bottomY ) / uiElementHeight );
            vertexList[i] = uiVertex;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with that please, I'am a beginner in unity and I've been searching for a solution for more than a month.
PS: i'am using unity 2017.3

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

**1**.Wrong class derivation

If you override the `ModifyVertices` function with the overload `List<UIVertex> vertices` parameter, you are supposed to make your script drive from [`BaseVertexEffect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.BaseVertexEffect.html) **not** `BaseMeshEffect`.

This *should have* worked:

```
public class Gradient : BaseVertexEffect 
{

    public override void ModifyVertices( List<UIVertex> vertexList )
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

but it **won't** since you are using Unity 2017.3. It should work for older version of Unity. See **#2** for more information and what to do.

**2**.Deprecated script and function

The fix from **#1** would have worked but you are using g Unity 2017.3.

`BaseVertexEffect` has been deprecated for a long time and has now been [*removed*](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.BaseVertexEffect.html) in Unity *2017.3.0p3*. You can no longer derive from the `BaseVertexEffect` script anymore and you can't use `void ModifyVertices(List<UIVertex> verts)` because it has been removed. A new overload has been added to replace it.

The new class to derive from is `BaseMeshEffect`. The function to override is `void ModifyMesh(Mesh mesh)`. Although, it looks like that has been replaced with `void ModifyMesh(VertexHelper vh)` so remove `ModifyMesh(Mesh mesh)` if you get any deprecated error.

Your new code should look something like this:

```
public class Gradient: BaseMeshEffect
{
    public override void ModifyMesh(VertexHelper vh)
    {

    }

    public override void ModifyMesh(Mesh mesh)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The class UI.BaseMeshEffect (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.BaseMeshEffect.html) has no function ModifyVertices you could override.

Overriding only works on functions the baseclass has and wich are marked as overrideable (virtual or abstract). In your case overriding makes no sense. All you can do is add the Function to your dervied class.

Comment: Can you explain to me how can I do that ?

Comment: @hatimboubakri: Do waht? Overriding? That is literally impossible. Adding a function to a dervied class? Just write the function in the derived class, no special keywords needed.